# PHP file_put_contents: failed to open stream: Protocol error

Tags: php, file, copy, file-get-contents

Saving an image using PHP copy or file_put_contents returns sometimes the following error: ***failed to open stream: Protocol error.***

This is the workflow I tried:

```
// A. using file_get_contents and file_put_contents
$image = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?key=' . $apiKey . '&photoreference=' . $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] . '&maxheight=300'

file_put_contents('googleimage/' . $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] . '.jpg', $image) // here is where the exception is thrown

// B. using copy
copy('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?key=' . $apiKey . '&photoreference=' . $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] . '&maxheight=300', 'googleimages/' . $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] . '.jpg');
```

This only happens sometimes, only for some pictures.

Comment: What does $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] contain on the records that throw exceptions?

Comment: it's the reference string google gives for the photo. Eg. CqQBlwAAAJMqc533H5kDibo444KqEkGjgnCWRKvmadBld3Aw_wlGom502_V3FJeg76SuGnRU77oriCREzQDZ21WtOhqT76l9ysb8aj5xWeKq7jUUTkwBZ5oWyQB7joGNca6SENMTeBY_DxGt2zrxCxouVFysg1rWaFbRA0wSMk1TGyGeY_zDFdP_I1qVp_aj5QlLFNNTpMYTNjf_YXzyTosjcAS8t5ESEMJIOAxBL1iQaOP1UH9eWxwaFH7WRElugeqGGG2srPd_wOAKvtLO

Answer (score 10):

The *Protocol Error* can occur when the proposed filename doesn't meet the specifications for filenames. For example, it includes reserved characters or is too long.

The error occurred in this line

```
file_put_contents('googleimage/' . $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] . '.jpg', $image)
```

and in a comment you gave an example of what  $mainPhoto['photo_reference'] can contain (and what doesn't work). 
Admittedly, I didn't expect to find reserved characters and didn't, so I tried to shorten it. See the comparison below (I removed characters from its end until it worked). Original string first, then shortened string.

```
CqQBlwAAAJMqc533H5kDibo444KqEkGjgnCWRKvmadBld3Aw_wlGom502_V3FJeg76SuGnRU77oriCREzQDZ21WtOhqT76l9ysb8aj5xWeKq7jUUTkwBZ5oWyQB7joGNca6SENMTeBY_DxGt2zrxCxouVFysg1rWaFbRA0wSMk1TGyGeY_zDFdP_I1qVp_aj5QlLFNNTpMYTNjf_YXzyTosjcAS8t5ESEMJIOAxBL1iQaOP1UH9eWxwaFH7WRElugeqGGG2srPd_wOAKvtLO
CqQBlwAAAJMqc533H5kDibo444KqEkGjgnCWRKvmadBld3Aw_wlGom502_V3FJeg76SuGnRU77oriCREzQDZ21WtOhqT76l9ysb8aj5xWeKq7jUUTkwBZ5oWyQB7joGNca6SENMTeBY_DxGt2zrxCxouVFysg1rWaFbRA0wSMk1TGyGeY_zDFdP_I1qVp_aj5QlLFNNTpMYTNjf_YXzyTosjcAS8t5ESEMJIOAxBL1iQaOP1UH9eWxwaFH7WREl
```

(You can try it out, also randomly shortening the string. However, removing the file I created this way is not that easy.)

> This only happens sometimes, only for some pictures.

I suspect that this depends on the google reference string you receive. The length may vary so much that it does make a difference.

---

See Microsoft's [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) from 2018.05.31:

For example, reserved characters (from [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions))

```
    < (less than)
    > (greater than)
    : (colon)
    " (double quote)
    / (forward slash)
    \ (backslash)
    | (vertical bar or pipe)
    ? (question mark)
    * (asterisk)
```

From Wikipedia's article [Filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename), section [Length Restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Length_restrictions):

> Some filesystems restrict the length of filenames.

The Wikipedia article [Comparison of Filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) contains a useful table [Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some images are too large and you need to increase your upload capacity or maximum execution time in `php.ini`:

```
 maximum_execution_time = 120
 memory_limit = 250M
```

Comment: hm, interesting, i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and **then I remembered that my local site was on Vagrant (Ubuntu guest), and my host machine was Windows 10.**

And my code had been pointing to folders like `K:\\F\\Users\\rcwalsh\\Documents\\code\\blahblah\\`.

I needed to change it to `/home/vagrant/Code/blahblah`.

And note that the tilde would not work either; I could not use `~/Code/blahblah`.

Comment: This time, the error was because I was calling `__FUNCTION__` thinking it would get the name of the function it was inside, but I'd forgotten that within that main function it was also wrapped in an anonymous closure, so `__FUNCTION__` was returning the closure, which couldn't be written as a string. So the string that I was trying to append to a filename was barfing "failed to open stream: Protocol error".