# PHP ZipArchive throwing warning on question mark in filename

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

ZipArchive is extracting to a windows filesystem, which doesn't like questionmarks in filenames. I'm getting this warning:

```
 Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(/sharednew/Discworld//56. Assassination? Impossible!.mp3): Failed to open   
  stream: Protocol error
```

Can I make ZipArchive work with these forbidden characters through config settings? Or can I catch some sort of exception to stop this from breaking my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP file\_put\_contents: failed to open stream: Protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650418/php-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-protocol-error)

Comment: No, it only confirms what I already know: a special character is throwing a warning. I want to know if I can handle this warning in some way or make ZipArchive correct invalid characters.

Comment: The list of disallowed characters is well known and not too long, perhaps `strtr($destination, '\\/:*?"<>|', '---------')` on the destination name can do the trick.

Comment: This is about a file inside a archive that I can't control, as it's downloaded from an external server.